# SQL - WHERE for 2nd SELECT object

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I'm trying to find an average of 2 items in my SQL table, an average commission of people who receive a commission from the table, and an average commission, including those who do not get a commission (null).

My code:

```
SELECT AVG(COMM) AVG_COMM, AVG(COMM) AVEALL
    FROM STAFF
        WHERE COMM IS NOT NULL;
```

This is what I get:

```
  AVG_COMM     AVEALL
---------- ----------
      97.5       97.5
```

This is what I want:

```
  AVG_COMM     AVEALL
---------- ----------
      97.5       27.851
```

This is what I want, the AVEALL is an average commission of everyone, including those with a null value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) to convert `NULL` values to 0 and then take the average to get your `AVEALL` value:

```
SELECT AVG(COMM) AVG_COMM, AVG(COALESCE(COMM, 0)) AVEALL
FROM STAFF
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36ae77cec646380758fe9f63079b8798)

Comment: Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 32
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Ibby1501 try using `COALESCE(COMM,0)` instead of `ISNULL(COMM,0)` for converting null values to 0.

Comment: OMFG It fucking worked! Thank you so much!  I was so confused about how this works as I am fairly new to SQL, and I need to learn this to pass my module. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ibby1501 sorry about the confusion with `ISNULL`, you didn't specify your DBMS so I assumed SQL server. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa thanks for your comment - I had to go away so I'm glad you were able to solve OPs issue in the mean time.

Comment: Done! Cheers! Also, are you available for a 1-1 chat?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you will need the following :

```
select avg (case when COMM is not null then COMM end) as AVG_COMM, avg(IF(COMM is null, 0, COMM)) as AVEALL from staff;
```

the 1st return only counts and calculates the average for those records which are not null, the 2nd return counts all the records and set records which are NULL to zero to calculate the average

Comment: I'm using ORACLE and I get this error:
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT AVG (CASE WHEN COMM IS NOT NULL THEN COMM END) AVG_COMM, 
        AVG(IF (COMM is null, 0, COMM)) AVEALL 
            from staff
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 22
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: For oracle, you need to use COALESCE or NVL